# Unable to convert date variable in Snowflake Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm facing an error while passing date records into variable .

Want to convert the records into date format 'YYYY-MM-DD' instead of 'Feb 20 2022 HH:MM:SS' format.

Do we have any date conversion methods in javascript ?.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_ADDWORKDAYS_CUTOFF_PP(SRC_DB STRING, SRC_SCHEMA STRING)
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
  
  var D_STARTDATE = '';
  var D_WORKDAYS = '';
  var seq_query = `SELECT "DELIV_CR_DT" AS D_STARTDATE,DERIVED_COL AS D_WORKDAYS  FROM `+SRC_DB+`.`+SRC_SCHEMA+`.v_v_testing`;
    var seq_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: seq_query});
    var seq_result = seq_stmt.execute(); 
    while (seq_result.next()){
    
    var STARTDATE = seq_result.getColumnValue(1);
    var WORKDAYS = seq_result.getColumnValue(2);
    var sub_call_query = `CALL `+SRC_DB+`.`+SRC_SCHEMA+`.sp_OTD_ADDWORKDAYS(`+STARTDATE+`,`+WORKDAYS+`,'01')`;
    var sub_call_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sub_call_query ,binds: [STARTDATE.toISOString(),WORKDAYS] });
    var sub_call_result = sub_call_stmt.execute(); 
    sub_call_stmt.next();
    var return_value = sub_call_result.getColumnValue(1);
}
  $$
;
```

**error:
SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 52 unexpected 'Feb'.
At Statement.execute, line 14 position 40 (line 36)**

Comment: Seems the error is coming from inner procedure call. Can you share what is in that proc - sp_OTD_ADDWORKDAYS?

Comment: A side topic... You have your `return_value` inside a loop. That will only return the value that's assigned the last time through the loop (last row in the result set). Also, it's not being returned so the output of the SP will be `NULL`.

Comment: Yea.. I removed the return statement from outside.. Inner Sp is having update statement and can see only one record is getting updated. May I know the issue with above Sp for not running in loops ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to include something like this in your logic for date conversion -

Using Java-script procedure -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "GETJOBS"(SRC_DB STRING, SRC_SCHEMA STRING)
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS caller
AS
$$

  var D_STARTDATE = '';
  var D_WORKDAYS = '';
  var seq_query = `SELECT to_char(to_timestamp('Feb 20 2022 10:10:10','Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS D_STARTDATE`;
    var seq_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: seq_query});
    var seq_result = seq_stmt.execute();
    seq_result.next();
    return seq_result.getColumnValue(1);

$$
;
```

Procedure call -

```
call getjobs('a','b');
```

| GETJOBS |
| --- |
| 2022-02-20 |

Using UDF -

```
create or replace function fn_getjobs(dt string)
returns string as
$$
select to_char(to_timestamp(dt,'Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as return_dt
$$
;
```

Function call

```
select fn_getjobs('Feb 20 2022 10:10:10') as dt;
```

| DT |
| --- |
| 2022-02-20 |